# averaging integers from an input list of numbers in python

Tags: python, math

I am new to coding and this is an intro coding class for python.
I must write a sister program that uses a loop to read and process a.txt document to obtain a list of random integers.
 The program must output all of the integers in the file on one line separated by spaces.
The program must also output the **average of the even integers and the average of the odd integers. Both averages must be expressed accurate to four decimal places.**

the bold text is what i need help with.. here is what i have so far.. I know how to set decimals, but i can't seem to figure out how to write for an average of the even and odd numbers.

```
def main():
    total = 0

    numfile = open('mynumbers.txt','r')

    line = numfile.readline()

    while line != '':
        numb = int(line)
        print(numb,end=' ')
        line = numfile.readline()
        #calculation for average of odds
        #calculation for average of evens


    numfile.close()
    print('\n' + 'Average of the even numbers:',)
    print('Average of the odd numbers:',)
main()
```

code output:

```
98 62 60 15 74 68 51 15 

Average of the even numbers: 

Average of the odd numbers:
```

my class example output:

```
40 90 89 57 90 19 88 78 

Average of the even numbers: 77.2000

Average of the odd numbers: 55.0000
```

Comment: So you want random numbers? Random numbers from the file? Or all numbers in the file? That isn't really clear...

Comment: i have the already randomized numbers being pulled from a .txt document. I need to add code that will average the evens and the odds from the list of randomized numbers that are being pulled from the .txt

Comment: The odds/evens test is a good way to learn the modulo function (%)

This returns the remainder of a division problem, so any integer % 2 which returns 0 is even, otherwise it's odd.

Example:

10 % 2 = 0
7 % 2 = 1
You can use % 2 to check for even/odd across the list of numbers, taking the appropriate action with each.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (see code comments for explanations):

```
def main():
    total = 0
    evens = []
    odds = []
    numfile = open('mynumbers.txt','r')

    line = numfile.readline()

    while line != '':
        numb = int(line)
        print(numb,end=' ')
        line = numfile.readline()
        # here you're checking each number and adding it to the apt list
        if numb%2 == 0:
           evens.append(numb)
        elif numb%2 == 1:
           odds.append(numb)

    numfile.close()
    # here you're getting the sum and rounding it
    e_avg = round(sum(evens)/len(evens),4)
    o_avg = round(sum(odds)/len(odds),4)

    print('\n' + 'Average of the even numbers: '+e_avg)
    print('Average of the odd numbers: '+o_avg)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the modulo (`%`) character can help you do evens and odds.  First, lets start by putting all the numbers in a list.

```
def main():
    total = 0

    numfile = open('mynumbers.txt','r')

    line = numfile.readline()

    nums = []

    while line != '':
        numb = int(line)
        print(numb,end=' ')
        nums.append(numb)
        line = numfile.readline()
        #calculation for average of odds
        #calculation for average of evens


    numfile.close()
    print('\n' + 'Average of the even numbers:',)
    print('Average of the odd numbers:',)
main()
```

Now at the end we can calculate the averages.  This will give you the average of the evens and odds.  It works by summing all the evens or odds, then dividing by the number of evens or odds.

Evens:

```
average = sum([i for i in nums if i%2==0])/len([i for i in nums if i%2==0])
```

and the average of the odds:

```
average_odds = sum([i for i in nums if i%2==1])/len([i for i in nums if i%2==1])
```

And to print those out to 4 decimal places:

```
print("Even Average: {0:.5}".format(average))
print("Odd Average: {0:.5}".format(average_odds))
```

**Now, since this is a homework assignment (I think), you should implement this into your full program.**

Comment: yes this is my homework and i don't expect anyone to completely do it for me, i thank you for the input!

Comment: No problem.  I also think it will *help you* if I give you parts of the code with an explanation and you put it together into a fully functioning program.

Comment: of course, and thats the best way to learn. I actually got it working and it works flawless. thanks :p

I was not expecting this much help so quickly haha.

Comment: @KiefferRay is there a reason you unaccepted my answer?